# Is storing objects of class with overloaded "operator&" in STL containers legal in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

According to C++03 Standard (23.1/3) only *copy-constructible* class objects can be stored in STL containers. *Copy-constructible* is described in 20.1.3 and requires that "&" yields address of the object.

Now suppose I have this class:

```
class Class {
public:
   Class* operator&()
   {
       //do some logging
       return this;
   }
   const Class* operator&() const
   {
       //do some logging
       return this;
   }
   //whatever else - assume it doesn't violate requierements
};
```

Can this class objects be legally stored in STL containers?

Comment: @VJovic: How? The overloaded operators yield the address of the object

Comment: @BjörnPollex If `class Class` contains member variable that is not copyable, then it doesn't matter whether operator& is overloaded - it is going to be noncopyable.

Comment: @VJovic: I've written "assume it doesn't violate requirements" exactly for that.

Comment: Is this question specifically about C++03? C++11 removes the requirement that containers' value types be copy constructible, and also removes the requirements on `&` for copy constructible types.

Comment: The question still doesn't make sense. If it doesn't violate requirements, then it can be stored. So, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @VJovic: I'm asking whether having `operator&()` overloaded like that and *all other code* in the class not violating requirements prevents storing the class objects in STL containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In C++03, the CopyConstructible requirements for `&`, given values `t` of type `T` and `u` of type `const T`, are:

- `&t` has type `T*`, and gives the address of `t`, and
- `&u` has type `const T*`, and gives the address of `u`.

Your overloaded operators have this behaviour; so, assuming the class meets the other CopyConstructible and Assignable requirements, values of this type can be stored in any C++03 container.

C++11 relaxes these requirements, requiring that types be movable or copyable only in containers or operations that specifically have such requirements, and removing the rather odd specification of what `&` must do; so your class is still fine, again assuming it meets all the other requirements for the particular container and set of operations you use.

Answer (score 1):

While in C++03 we *only* had the possibility to copy construct / copy assign objects, we get two additional, by far more powerful tools to construct objects and one additional tool to assign objects: move construction and assignment and emplace construction (based on perfect forwarding).

Thanks to that, the standard gives the `value_type` of a container way more leeway in its requirements. For example, you are allowed to store `unique_ptr`s, which are move-only, in a `std::vector`, as long as you don't use any operations that require *CopyConstructible*, *CopyInsertable* or *CopyAssignable* (such as assignment of one container to another).

> Can this class objects be legally stored in STL containers?

**Yes**, *none* of the requirements that *may* be used in a container instantiated with a certain `value_type` even mention the address-of operator in any way.

`§17.6.3.1 [utility.arg.requirements]`

> The template definitions in the C++ standard library refer to various named requirements whose details are set out in tables 17–24.

(Table 17 and 18 are Comparable requirements)

```
Table 19 — DefaultConstructible requirements [defaultconstructible]
Expression               Post-condition
T t;                     object t is default-initialized
T u{};                   object u is value-initialized
T()                      a temporary object of type T is value-initialized
T{}

Table 20 — MoveConstructible requirements [moveconstructible]
Expression               Post-condition
T u = rv;                u is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction
T(rv)                    T(rv) is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction
rv’s state is unspecified

Table 21 — CopyConstructible requirements (in addition to MoveConstructible) [copyconstructible]
Expression               Post-condition
T u = v;                 the value of v is unchanged and is equivalent to u
T(v)                     the value of v is unchanged and is equivalent to T(v)

Table 22 — MoveAssignable requirements [moveassignable]
Expression    Return type    Return value    Post-condition
t = rv        T&             t               t is equivalent to the value of
                                             rv before the assignment
rv’s state is unspecified.

Table 23 — CopyAssignable requirements(in addition to MoveAssignable) [copyassignable]
Expression    Return type    Return value    Post-condition
t = v         T&             t               t is equivalent to v, the value of
                                             v is unchanged

Table 24 — Destructible requirements [destructible]
Expression               Post-condition
u.~T()                   All resources owned by u are reclaimed, no exception is propagated.
```

Then we also got the container requirements themselves. Those are based on their allocator types:

`§23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] p13`

> All of the containers defined in this Clause and in (21.4) except array meet the additional requirements of an allocator-aware container, as described in Table 99.
>   Given a container type **`X`** having an allocator_type identical to **`A`** and a **`value_type`** identical to **`T`** and given an lvalue **`m`** of type **`A`**, a pointer **`p`** of type **`T*`**, an expression **`v`** of type **`T`**, and an rvalue **`rv`** of type **`T`**, the following terms are defined. (If **`X`** is not allocator-aware, the terms below are defined as if **`A`** were **`std::allocator<T>`**.)
>
> - **`T`** is *CopyInsertable into **`X`*** means that the following expression is well-formed:
>         `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);`
> - **`T`** is *MoveInsertable into **`X`*** means that the following expression is well-formed:
>         `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv);`
> - **`T`** is *EmplaceConstructible into **`X`** from **`args`***, for zero or more arguments **`args`**, means that the following expression is well-formed:
>         `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args);`

An excerpt from the table for sequence containers (where `p` is a valid const iterator and `t` is an lvalue of type `T`):

> `a.insert(p,t)`
>   *Requires:* **`T`** shall be CopyInsertable into **`X`**. For **`vector`** and **`deque`**, **`T`** shall also be CopyAssignable.
>   *Effects:* Inserts a copy of t before p.

If you never use that specific `insert` variant (and other members, that require CopyInsertible), your type doesn't need to be CopyInsertable. Easy as that. Same goes for all the other members. The ***only*** requirement that *must* be fulfilled is the Destructible requirement (logical, isn't it?).